# Subobject classifier in $Sets^{Q}$

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

> Let **Q** be the linearly ordered set of rational numbers considered as a category while **$R^{+}$** is the set of reals with $\infty$. In $Sets^{Q}$,prove that the subobject classifier $\Omega$ has $\Omega(q)=\{$$r| r\in$ **$R^{+}$** , $r\geq q$ $\}$

I'm not sure how to start. Should I find the natural transformations needed in the pullback and then prove uniqueness of $\phi$: P $\implies$ $\Omega$?

I've been trying to find an  analogy with the S.C in $Sets^{C^{op}}$ but without good results.

I'd appreciate hints rather than complete solutions.

Comment: This is really just a special case of what happens in a presheaf category. Try again.

Comment: But  in that case shouldn't i be working with $Q^{op}$ ? ( I'm using there's a unique arrow from p to q iff $p \leq q$)

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to its opposite, so it doesn't really matter.